# Sending notifications by schedule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to send mail on a schedule specified by the admin. Admin can specify two days in which is sending mail. The days which are specified through the admin interface, it days before the termination of activity of the company.

I would use `Whenver` for this.

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end

class CreateEmails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :emails do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :value
      t.index :name, unique: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

set :output, "#{path}/log/cron_rails_app.log"

every 5.minutes do
  rake "delivery_campaign_status:start"
end

class NotifyEndedCampaigns

  def start
    @end_day = Setting.find_by(name: 'notify_day_from').value
    @campaigns = Campaign.where(notified: false).where("ends_at < ?",  Time.now + @end_day.to_i.day )

    @campaigns.each do |campaign|
      CampaignEndedMailer.notify(campaign, @end_day).deliver
      campaign.notified = true
      campaign.save
    end
  end
end

require 'notify_ended_campaigns'

namespace :delivery_campaign_status do
  desc 'nitify Campaign end day'

  task start: :environment do
    puts 'Start sending ended campaigns notifications'
    NotifyEndedCampaigns.new.start
  end
end
```

I made right?

Comment: Isnt this the same question you asked yesterday?

Comment: What's the update mate? did you manage to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'll say its not the best practice, you should move the logic of actual checking and sending the email into a separate rake task and you will use whenever to call the rake task every 5 minutes, and check in the rake task for models which full fills the criteria of notification.
 This [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks) will help you get started with rake. 
 I'll suggest you should just create a method in your model that email the company and do the rest in the rake task, that usually resides in /project/lib/task directory